# A shell script to to replace a value in all the existing files with the same name having different folder names

Tags: linux, shell, scripting

My folder structure:-

```
Container(Main folder)
subcontainer1(inside this we have a file package.json)
subcontainer2 (inside this we have a file package.json)
subcontainer3 (inside this we have a file package.json)
```

This below command is working for a particular folder as I have given the exact path

My requirement is to update all the files which are under these folders as there can be any so that should be dynamic

Working Command is:-

```
sed -i -e 's/publicConfigRepoUrl/publicConfigUrl2/g' Container/subcontainer1/package.json
```

what I have tried and that is not working:-

```
sed -i -e 's/publicConfigRepoUrl/publicConfigUrl2/g' Container\/[A-Za-z]*[0-9]*\/package.json
```

In this I have tried to cover all the folder which are inside the container folder but it is not working.

Comment: `find . -name package.json -exec sed [... your sed command ...] {} \; -print`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution which worked for me is:-
sed -i -e “s/publicConfigRepoUrl/publicConfigUrl2/g” Container/*/package.json